# LazyLoad Unviel position absolute

Tags: jquery, jquery-lazyload, android-lazyloading

I'm using lazyload unviel but for some reason it wont load the images I have positioned in absolute.

https://github.com/luis-almeida/unveil

How can I approach this issue?  Is their a different Lazyload i should use instead?